# Is it possible for light sources in Cycles to have nonphysical falloff like in BI?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

In BI, we have the traditional OpenGL choices of constant, linear and <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>distance<sup>2</sup></sub> falloff, along with some parameters to tweak the falloff formula.  This allowed for a variety of artistic styles, and getting even illumination from lamps that couldn't be put far away.

Cycles is more physically realistic.  What about 3D works in which we don't want such great realism?  Is there a way to make all the light paths between two objects, or between one object and all others, obey alternative laws of radiation physics?

Comment: possible duplicate of [changing the intensity falloff of light sources using Cycles nodes](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10770/changing-the-intensity-falloff-of-light-sources-using-cycles-nodes)

Comment: @David That question is newer and is already being closed as a duplicate of this one.. Why close this older question as a duplicate of the new question?

Comment: @gandalf3 The answer to the newer question is better.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. There is a node called *Light Falloff*
you can plug in to the Emission shader strength.
It has three outputs: *quadratic* or *Linear*
or *Constant* You my even do some math with the ray
length and plug the result in the *Light Falloff*
node strength and use the *Constant* output.
The example is only a demonstration nothing useful.

[image: Falloff Demo]