# changing the intensity falloff of light sources using Cycles nodes

Tags: cycles-render-engine

So generally people tend to agree that the intensity of light has a fall-off that is the inverse square of the distance to the light.

Something like:  **intensity  = 1.0 / (distance * distance);**

I'm fairly certain from what people say that this would be used in OSL/Cycles since it's supposed to be physically based however it's useful to have control over this when a scene is being difficult or even just to give more control when using several fill lights.

I'd like to find a node setup that can help modulate(or replace) the current falloff with something that is a bit more linear.

**intensity = 1.0 / distance;**

So does anyone have an idea on how to control the intensity falloff using what we have available to us already?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the "light falloff" node to control the strength of the emitter.

quadratic

[image]

linear

[image]

constant

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it didn't occur to me to look in the 'Color' section.