# I was wondering how you'd go about creating a visible cone of light that fades

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I was wondering if it was possible to do something like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24493/is-it-possible-to-make-visible-spotlight-lightrays) but also apply the effect used in [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10770/changing-the-intensity-falloff-of-light-sources-using-cycles-nodes) to the cone of light in Cycles.  I was told by someone else that I need volumetrics, but I'm not quite sure how to do this.

Comment: You can apply such falloff manipulations to any lamp. For volumetrics, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8001/599