# Is it possible to have Blender render rays of light that fade away?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I was wondering if it's possible to have Blender render visible light that fade away the farther it gets from the light source in Cycles render?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1818/is-it-possible-for-light-sources-in-cycles-to-have-nonphysical-falloff-like-in-b

Comment: That's definitely part of what I'm looking for, is it possible to use that process with something like [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24493/is-it-possible-to-make-visible-spotlight-lightrays) where you can see like say, a distinct cone of light before it fades away?

Comment: You need volumetrics to do that. please ask that as a separate question.